Azure DevOps- Query to get User story story point and sum of efforts logged under task for each use story
Is there a way to get the story point for each user story and corresponding sum of efforts logged for tasks under the user story, For example- User Story A has story point 3 and it has 3 tasks and team has added 5 hour for each task, so the query need to have  User Story point- 3 and efforts 15


Is there a way to get the story point for each user story and corresponding sum of efforts logged for tasks under the user story

I am afraid that the Queries in Azure DevOps doesn't support showing the sum of the efforts for the tasks. It only supports showing the effort value of the single task and the story points of single User Story.
For example:

For a workaround, I suggest that you can use the built-in feature: Rollup column in Boards -> Backlog to show the story points and the sum of the task efforts.
Here is an example:
Rollup Column:

Column Settings:

Result:

Here is a suggestion ticket about adding rollup columns to Boards Query: Could you add rollup columns on queries?
